# windows forms closing immediately when opened

Tags: c#, winforms

When I open a new form from my login screen, it logs the user in, shows the form then instantly disappears???

Here is my code for the relevant parts:

```
string checkAdmin = "select * from Logins where Name = @userName and UserType ='Admin'";
string checkUser = "select * from Logins where Name = @userName and UserType ='User'";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=loginsTest;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
{
   using (var checkAdminCommand = new SqlCommand(checkAdmin, connection))
   {
      //guessing at the column length here. Use actual column size instead of 20
      checkAdminCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = userNameBox.Text;
      connection.Open();

      if (checkAdminCommand.ExecuteScalar() != null)
      {
         adminScreen admnscrn = new adminScreen();
         admnscrn.Show();
         this.Close();
         return;
      }

      else
      {
      }
   }

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=loginsTest;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
{
   using (var checkUserCommand = new SqlCommand(checkUser, connection))
   {
      //guessing at the column length here. Use actual column size instead of 20
      checkUserCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = userNameBox.Text;

      connection.Open();
      if (checkUserCommand.ExecuteScalar() != null)
      {
         userScreen usrscrn = new userScreen();
         usrscrn.Show();
         this.Close();
      }

      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Invalid details, try again");
         passwordBox.Text = "";
      }
   }
}
```

So when I open usrscrn or admnscrn, it flicks up and goes straight back off again? I've tried researching, I've used Application.Run(userScreen()); etc, it just throws an exception saying something about a second message loop?

I have created a new screen, set it as MDI, and entered this code:

```
        private void MDI_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 loginscrn = new Form1();
        loginscrn.Show();
    }
```

my program.cs file contains this code:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MDI_Form());
    }
```

will this work??

Comment: what this  this.Close(); for ? are you inside another form ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging??

Comment: the form i am in (login screen) has to disappear when i open the user or admin screen, so when i open the relevant screen (userScreen usrscrn = new userScreen();
                    usrscrn.Show();) then it closes the login screen

Comment: yes, but when i run it in visual studio, the form stays open. when i built the solution however, it closes instantly

Comment: Remove this.Close() and let us know the results

Comment: `admnscrn.Show(); this.Close();` O_O

Comment: it seems, after debugging step by step, it closes the window, shows the new form, then continues the code, right to the end then closes the window. How do i stop it running this??

Comment: `it just throws an exception saying something` What is that something? Whenever you're getting an exception, *always* post the *full* exception.

Comment: Why are you using `this` and not the qualified name for the object you are closing?

Comment: it works, but now the login screen is still open. i need it to disappear when the new window opens?

Comment: i always assumed you used `this` when doing something to the form you were in?

Comment: **What is the exception you are getting?** And where exactly is it happening?

Comment: "i always assumed you used this when doing something to the form you were in? "  It does.  Where do you think your code is executing from?  hint: your login screen.  When you close it, everything else will to.

Comment: @tnw Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.

Comment: Your ```Form loginscrn``` is declared within the MDI_Form_Load procedure { } and, since it is not a modal dialog, it goes out of scope when it exits the procedure { }.  loginscrn will either self dispose() or worse; leak or prevent your application from closing.

Comment: Your userscrn and adminscrn are declared within the scope of using () { } and go out of that scope and behave unexpectedly by either self disposing or leaking.  Fix by either declaring the userscrn and adminscrn outside of the using() { } scope, or make them static.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need MDI Form (Multi Document Interface) that will let other forms to be inside it , so when you close one form it will not terminate all the application .

Or 
make your login form not the starup form , by creating another hidden form and make it the startup one

Comment: mdi form? is that like a master form?

Comment: yes , mark your main form as MDI , it is in form properties , then add these two forms to it .

Comment: This is incorrect if the design of the application is not intended to be an MDI window.

Comment: i cant find MDI property?

Comment: the guy didnt know about MDI form , it is better to have MDI form when you have more than one form

Comment: MDI forms are designed to have a parent window with multiple child forms.  For example, in Photoshop you have the main window and you have all the child windows which you can tile/dock/move around.  This is not at all relevant to his scenario where he simply is trying to start his application with one form, then close it and open another form.

Comment: Basically i want a login screen to show up, then when they successfully log in, i want the login window to close and the main screen (depending on user type) to show up

Comment: the problem when you close the main form all the sub classes will close , let see if any one will give you a solution without using MDI form

Comment: I would point out the Microsoft is slowly moving away from the MDI interface, it is not as well understood by users and not as flexible in general as the floating windows approach. MDI is still a good choice at time, but not just because your have more than 1 form.

Comment: @sino please see my updated question, see if i have done this correctly

Comment: Yes this should be fine , let us know

Comment: it works, but i set this in the mdi forms function:this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
            this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
            Form1 loginscrn = new Form1();
            loginscrn.Show();

Comment: now when it starts the login screen and other windows appear behind the mdi form?

Comment: set it show show as modal , there are options in form properties to adjust that

Comment: read this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435634/child-form-opened-behind-the-controls-of-the-main-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: i have tried the BringToFront(), but it still goes to the back? tried it on mdi form (loginscrn.BringToFront();) and on the login screen (BringToFront();)??

Comment: You might want to have your login form be either a child window or shown modally from your MDI window if you are taking this approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

This is the boilerplate bootstrap code in most Windows Forms projects.  It creates a Form which should act as your main window and it calls `Application.Run` on it.  This causes it to run a message loop which allows the Form to execute in an event-driven manner (waiting for user input).  When you call `Close` on this main form, your `Application.Run` method returns and your `Main` method runs to completion which causes your program to exit.

It sounds to me like what you want to do is show a form like a splash screen or login window, then when it closes you want to show another form and run the *second* form as your main form.

To do that, there are at least a couple approaches:

- Modify the `Main` method so that it creates the login form, calls `Application.Run` on it and waits for it to close, then analzes the result through a property such as the `DialogResult` property to know whether it was a success.  Then it could later create your main form and again call `Application.Run` on it.

In this case your code might look like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

    Application.Run(loginForm);

    if (loginForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
    else
    {
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

- Alternatively, you might modify the `Main` method to run the main form instead of the login form, then have the main form show the login window as a dialog using the `Form.ShowDialog` method.  You could try doing this before the main form is even shown yet, or have the main form `Visible` property set to false so that it appears that your login window is actually the main window.

Here is how you'd do that:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;

    using (var loginForm = new LoginForm())
    {
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Error handling
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to make sure that your LoginForm correctly sets `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` or something else as needed to signal a successful login.