# child windows always go to back

Tags: c#, winforms

i have an MDI form, and when i start the program, the child window that opens always goes to the back, i have tried sendtoback() on the MDI form, bringtofront() on the child form, no luck. Anyone?

```
private void MDI_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SendToBack();
   Form1 loginscrn = new Form1();
   loginscrn.Show();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BringToFront();
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=loginsTest;Trusted_Connection=yes");
   connection.Open();
   string selection = "select * from Logins where Name = '"+userNameBox.Text+"'";
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selection, connection);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: I think the answer you _didn't mark_ in your [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189413/windows-forms-closing-immediately-when-opened) has a more correct implementation for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's either:

```
loginscrn.ShowDialog(this);
```

to make it a dialog, or:

```
loginscrn.MdiParent = this;
loginscrn.Show();
```

if that form is suppose to be a mdi child.

Comment: The loginscrn is supposed to be a child window of the MDI Form, but i dont know how to enable it, i assumed it was automatically a child form?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **Owner** property. "An owner window can never cover an owned window." For more info, read this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx)

EDIT: Calling BringToFront() in form_load won't do you any good, as the form isn't visible at this time. You could try moving it to OnShown.

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BringToFront();
        base.OnShown(e);
    }
```